# Consultas con tabla pivote - Laravel y jQuery

Tags: jquery, laravel

Buenas tardes estoy haciendo un filtrador con selectores. Bien, lo primero que se selecciona es la ciudad de donde quieres ver las escapadas.

```
//Selector de ciudad
<div class="form-group">
   <select class="form-control inputs_filters maxwi" id="ciudad" name="ciudad">
     <option value="">Elige</option>
        @foreach ($ciudades as $item)
           <option value="{{ $item->slug }}" {{ ($ciudad == $item->slug) ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $item->name }}</option>
        @endforeach
   </select>
</div>

//Selector casa
<div class="margen_filtros">
    <label for="" class="opciones_filtrosLabel">Casa</label>
     <div class="form-group">
        <select class="form-control inputs_filters maxwi2" id="lasCasas" name="lasCasas" disabled>
        </select>
     </div>
</div>
```

Esto lo mando por AJAX a mi controlador:

```
var ciudad = "";
var casa = "";

$('#ciudad').on('change', function(prueba) {
  ciudad=document.getElementById('ciudad').value;
  filtrar();
});

function filtrar(){ 
   var url = '/filtrar-escapada';
   $.ajax({
      headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') },
      type: "POST",
      url: url,
      data: {
        'ciudad' : ciudad,
        'casa_id' : casa
      },
      success: function(resultado){
          //según la ciudad marcada obtenida por AJAX muestro las casas disponibles en un selector
          $.each(resultado.casas, function(fetch, casa){
            $('#lasCasas').append('<option value="'+ casa.id +'">'+ casa.name +'</option>');
          });
      }
   });
}
```

**Para sacar las casas hago lo siguiente**

```
public function filtrarEscapada(Request $request)
    {
        //Primero según el slug que recibo hago una consulta para poder sacar la id de esa ciudad
        $ciudad = Ciudades::where('slug', $request->ciudad)->first();
        //Si el campo que recibo con el slug no esta vacio, añado una condición con un where para que me saque las casas que tiene esa ciudad
        $casas = Casas::query()->where('estado', 1);
                if(!empty($request->ciudad))
                {
                    $casas->where('ciudad_id', $ciudad->id);
                }
                $casas = $casas->get();
        //Hago lo mismo con las escapadas, son los resultados que pertenecen a esa ciudad
        $escapadas = Escapadas::query()->where('estado', 1);
                if(!empty($request->ciudad))
                {
                    $escapadas->where('ciudad_id', $ciudad->id);
                }
                $escapadas = $escapadas->get();
                
                
        return with(['casas' => $casas, 'escapadas' => $escapadas]);
    }
```

Bien aquí hasta aquí funciona todo bien, pero si ahora pulso sobre el selector de casa rellenado por lo de antes, quiero obtener la `id` de la casa, y en base a esa `id` mostrar solo las escapadas posibles con esa casa.

```
//Aquí obtengo la id de la casa que selecciono, la mando a la funcion `filtrar()` para así modificar la consulta.
$('#lasCasas').on('change', function(prueba) {
    casa=document.getElementById('lasCasas').value;
       filtrar();
});
```

Pero no se como hacer para filtrar que solo me muestre las escapadas que pertenecen a esa casa.

> Para aclarar más:
>
> Cada casa pertenece a una ciudad_id 
> Cada escapada pertenece a una
> ciudad_id 
> Las escapadas pueden pertenecer a una sola casa

**Añado mi relación con la tabla pivote**

```
class Escapadas extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'escapadas';
    protected $primaryKey='id';

    public function casasEscapada()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Casas::class, 'escapada_casas', 'escapada_id', 'casa_id');
    }
}
```

**He probado haciendo un `join`, de este modo me funciona, pero no se si es el más correcto**

```
if(!empty($request->casa_id))
  {
   $escapadas->join('escapada_casas', 'escapadas.id', 'escapada_casas.escapada_id')->where('escapada_casas.casa_id', $request->casa_id);
   }
```

**Mi tabla `casas`**

| id | name | slug | ciudad_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | casa 1 | foto.jpg | 2 |
| 2 | casa 2 | foto.jpg | 1 |

**Mi tabla `escapadas`**

| id | titulo | slug | ciudad_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | escapada 1 | foto.jpg | 1 |
| 2 | escapada 2 | foto.jpg | 1 |

**Mi tabla `escapadas_casas` pivote**

| id | escapada_id | casa_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 |

Comment: No se entiende tu problema, se que quieres filtrar con los **select**, pero estos existen desde el principio?, cuantos son?, las tres tablas se generan con una sola petición?, los select son por nivel y muestran cada una de las tablas independientemente?, que es una escapada?, si puedes explicarte mejor, añade tu HTML para ver como es la estructura.

Comment: Hola @AntonioGalicia he añadido el html del selector de casa que se rellena con la respuesta del ajax. Una escapada es como ir a visitar un museo en una ciudad

Comment: Voy a añadir una consulta con `join` que he probado y funciona a medias para haber si se comprende mejor

Comment: Si no entiendo mal, tienes que seleccionar los tres **select** para poder pintar la información, el primer **select** _ciudad_ pinta al segundo _casas_, luego con _casas_ quieres pintar un tercero _escapadas_, al seleccionar los tres mostrar una tabla con información, estoy en lo correcto?, corrígeme, serian **select** de tres niveles is es asi.

Comment: Nop, realmente es un selector de ciudad y otro de selección de casa. Pero con el movimiento de todos ellos siempre muestra resultados. Si no selecciona ninguna ciudad muestra todas las escapadas, si selecciona ciudad se muestra solo las escapadas de esa ciudad y si elige casa solo muestra los permitidos por esa casa. En mi pregunta puse la solución que funciona perfectamente, pero no se si es la correcta